# How to plan tkinter GUI in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, project-planning

I am writing a simple menu-based RPG (combat is turn-based and such), but I have realized I had better organize all of my widgets before I actually start implementing the GUI. My application "changes windows" by lifting frames containing widgets or other frames (or both). Is there a commonly-used or suggested method or organization program to help me keep track of everything neatly before I start?

Thanks.

Comment: this may be better answered on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you tried pen and paper?

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a more dynamic way to do this. Thanks anyway guys.

Comment: Pencil and paper.  Don't plan it in too much detail; as soon as you see it on the screen, you'll want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say do health as a number like 0/1 then you could do this line of code for a label.

```
new_label = tkinter.Label(window, text="Health: %s/%s" % current_health, max_health,bg="green")
new_label.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
```

that would assign variables to your label for may health and current health and display it on the left of your screen. Also it will have a green background ofr the label but that can be changed. Really that is basic gui in a tkinter application hope this helped.